# How can I implement downHeap() function in a min-heap?

Tags: c++, data-structures, min-heap

I'm trying to write downHeap() function for a min-heap where I will check to see if a root node's child is less than the rootnode and if so, I will swap their values. The class Node is already defined for me and has a 'left' and 'right' child ptrs as well as 'value'. Below is my code so far:

```
void downHeap(Node *n) {

    if (!n) {return;}

    if (!n->left && !n->right) {return;}

    if (n->left && n->right){
        if (n->left->value < n->right->value){
          if (n->left->value < n->value){
            std::swap(n->value, n->left->value);
            downHeap(n->left);
          }
      else if (n->right->value < n->left->value){
          if (n->right->value < n->value){
            std::swap(n->value, n->right->value);
            downHeap(n->right);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is my main to test the function:

```
int main() {
  Node *n = new Node(7);
  n->left = new Node(6);
  n->right = new Node(9);
  n->left->left = new Node(4);
  n->left->right = new Node(5);
  downHeap(n);
  printTreeVertical(n);

  delete n;
  n = nullptr;
  return 0;
}
```

And my resulting tree:

```
##6 (X) Greater than child value 4
#|
#|_ 4.  // 4 is left child and 9 is right child of 6 in this tree.
#|..|
#|..|_ 7 //7 and 5 are children of 4.
#|..|..|
#|..|..|_ [null]
#|..|..|
#|..|..|_ [null]
#|..|
#|..|_ 5
#|.....|
#|.....|_ [null]
#|.....|
#|.....|_ [null]
#|
#|_ 9
#...|
#...|_ [null]
#...|
#...|_ [null]
```

As you can see 6 is the rootNode whereas 4 should be. And then 4 and 5 should swap places again. My function right now seems to swap the rootNode only once and keeps going down but does not recheck from the start. I've tried to add `downHeap(n)` again at the end of the if conditions but if I do that, nothing outputs. Please help!

Comment: Can anyone help me? I've spent a long time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to go down in depth, then check for the condition to swap.
I would do something like this:

```
void mySwap(Node* a, Node* b)
{
    int tmp = a->val;
    a->val = b->val;
    b->val = tmp;
}

void downHeap(Node* root)
{
    node_t* tmp = NULL;

    if(root == NULL) return;

    downHeap(root->left);
    downHeap(root->right);

    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) return;

    if(root->left != NULL && root->right != NULL)
    {
        if(root->left->val < root->right->val)
            tmp = root->left;
        else 
            tmp = root->right;
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->left != NULL)
            tmp = root->left;
        if(root->right != NULL)
            tmp = root->right;
    }

    if(tmp->val < root->val)
        mySwap(root, tmp);
}
```

When you are done with left and right subtrees check for the current node's children.

If the current node is a leaf (i.e. no children) there's nothing to do.

If the current node has two children then get the minimum between the two.

If the current node has only one child, that is your `tmp` to check against.

At the end check for the swap condition.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. I tried it with your code however it still doesn't swap properly in the subtree. I will continue to work on it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mention that `swap` is not std::swap, it's a custom swap working on node pointers

Comment: I tried to do std::swap(n->value, tmp->value) Let me try swapping manually.

Comment: I get 4 as root but 7 and 9 as next children. Then 6 and 5 as children of 7. Whereas 5 should be swapped with 7.

Comment: Call `downHeap` repeatedly until no swaps are made

Comment: Omg I've got it. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, I was able to use ```std::swap(n->value, tmp->value)```;

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not sure if this would be top down approach but the time complexity in this case would be better than the other one.